# Dynamic SQL to query an Adventureworks table

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I am trying to see a list of tables from Adventureworks DB from "Person" schema in Sql Server 2008.  I developed the following SP, but after running it as follows it gives me error "Incorrect syntax near ')'".  Do you know how I can revise this SP or exec statement?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [getTableNames]
@SchemaName VARCHAR(50)
AS

BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET @SchemaName = 'PERSON'
DECLARE @cmd AS VARCHAR(max)
SET @SchemaName = RTRIM(@SchemaName)
SET @cmd = N'SELECT TABLE_NAME ' + 
'FROM information_schema.Tables ' +
'WHERE TABLE_TYPE = ''BASE TABLE'' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @SchemaName'
END

exec sp_executesql getTableNames, N'@SchemaName NVARCHAR(50), @SchemaName'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need dynamic SQL:

```
select * from sys.tables
where type_desc = 'BASE TABLE' and schema_id = schema_id(@SchemaName)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works too but I like the other solution a little better since I need to run a SP from my C# code.

Comment: This is just the SQL that works and can be in a SP or not.  Just put this between the begin and end of your SP and you are done.

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually need to use dynamic SQL here, plus your sproc isn't quite right as you're not executing the @cmd statement. Just use:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [getTableNames]
@SchemaName VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM information_schema.Tables
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @SchemaName
END

EXECUTE getTableNames 'PERSON'
```